# Does ES6 `let` and `const` only work in compile time when compiled with babel?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I tried babel in babel's official REPL, and found that `let`, `const` only compiled to be `var`.

Does that mean that `let` and `const` only take effect in compile time? Or `let` and `const` do take effects in compiled codes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Babel does [escape analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_analysis) to detemine if there is actually a functional difference between the way `var` and `let` is used - so:

```
let x = 5;
```

Usually just gets compiled to

```
var x = 5;
```

Whereas:

```
let x = 5;
{ 
  let x = 10;
}
```

gets compiled to:

```
var x = 5;
{
  var x2 = 10; // _x actually, 
}
```

This is done because it's much faster than the way old compilers (like traceur) did block scoping in ES5. Block scoping is actually possible in ES5 - it's just really ugly:

```
let x = 5;
```

Gets transpiled to:

```
try { throw 5; } catch (x) {
  // x defined in this scope
}
```

Comment: This is only true for the `es2015` preset. What Babel compiles to depends on the preset you are using.

Answer (score 1):

What Babel compiles to depends on the presets you are using.

Check out this example [here](https://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBARgGwIYwLwwORQKbQwbgChCAzAVzGCgEtwYALbBBEACgEoYBvQmGAJ2xQy_MDAA8AE2oA3AHwAJJixgB3EPwSSANN0RIAvgEJxEAA5IwcnNHEB6c5bn3p8ogcJA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2017%2Creact&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.2.2). On the left panel you can change the presets. Clicking through these presets, you will notice how the compiled code changes.

Babel will only compile `const` and `let` to `var` if you are using the `es2015` or `es2015-loose` preset. Which preset you are using depends on you requirements which browsers you have to support.

As Benjamin pointed out in his answer, if you use the `es2015` presets, Babel will still compile it in a way, where the concept of `const` and `let` will be conserved.

Answer (score 0):

`const` is in fact [widely supported natively](http://caniuse.com/#feat=const) these days, including in IE11.

[Similarly for](http://caniuse.com/#feat=let) `let`, with a small caveat in IE11.

So – unless you're targeting IE10 and below, there is no need to transpile any more.

Comment: That wasn't the question, though. The question was what `const` and `let` gets compiled to when using Babel.

Comment: Depends on what browsers / runtimes are being targeted though, `const` and `let` might just be compiled to `const` and `let`